# How to fix "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" Error With Tomcat and J2EE Web Application?

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Following configuration I am using in server.xml file.

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       keystoreFile="/home/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="password" clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS"  ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" />
```

How to resolve this issue ..

Comment: What software gave you the `ERR_SSL_...` error message? Have you run a [TLS scan](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) on your site?

Comment: No i did not run any TLS scan . Simply i tried to open my site in chrome as usual and it was giving me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I modified the ciphers from ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"  to    ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
         SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"                    and it worked for me .
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a single cipher (the RC4 one) will only enable a single cipher, rather than adding a single cipher to a default set. You enabled (only) an RC4-based cipher, and Google Chrome has removed RC4 support entirely, so there's no way for Google Chrome to handshake with that server.